# How to debug Access token validation against Identityserver4

Tags: angular, authorization, jwt, access-token, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 to validate angular 4 client to secure a WebApi.
but I am running into 401 on authorization. I need a way to debug Access token validation process to help me figure out the issue.

Comment: Enable logging in your API - this will give you more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that I used
app.UseMvc(); before app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication in startup class Configure() function

Comment: Just to make it clear, you have to register Authentication service before register the routing